# Windowsでポピュラーなスニペットツールは何ですか？

Tags: windows, atom-editor

お世話になります。

Windowsでポピュラーなスニペットツールは何ですか？

MacではDashを使っているので、もし似たようなものがあれば教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zealはどうでしょう？

https://zealdocs.org/
atomのプラグインもあります
https://github.com/futhrevo/atom-zeal